# How do I create smooth, realistic ribbon cloth?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, cloth-simulation

[image]

Hey Guys I want to replicate the ribbons in this photograph in blender. So far I know how to create thin tubes using curve modifier with a circle as the offset. but I don't know how to create the smooth waves that naturally occur in a velvet ribbon like in the picture above. Can y'all help guide me through this, thanks!

[image]

I basically used a cloth sim to make this ribbon, but I want to know the different ways I can achieve this ribbon mesh, and also how to create the middle knot in the ribbon and to create and edit the ribbon for different objects/bottles.

Comment: Hello could you please highlight the small waves you're talking about and also maybe show what you've done so far?

Comment: @moonboots I have added a answer that might help you understand my situation

Comment: Please don't use the Your Answer field to add precisions, instead edit your original post, what you've done seems pretty good no?

Comment: Just did, thanks for the clarification @moonboots